# Android Image Resize basic

Tags: android, android-layout

I like to resize an bitmap,if it is big make it small and place it on an specific location in the surface view, I need to get device width and height and then bitmap size and place them in an surface view and then take another image resize it and place it in any location has i like.
How to know the location co ordinates first(to place second image - this should be device independent if larger/smaller screen layout should not change)

and how to scale an big bitmap and set as background so i can draw an image over it.
my code :

```
final int canvasWidth = getWidth();
final int canvasHeight = getHeight();

int imageWidth = img.getWidth();
int imageHeight = img.getHeight();

float scaleFactor = Math.min( (float)canvasWidth / imageWidth, 
                              (float)canvasHeight / imageHeight );
Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(  img, 
                                            (int)(scaleFactor * imageWidth), 
                                            (int)(scaleFactor * imageHeight), 
                                            true );
canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
canvas.drawBitmap(scaled, 10, 10, null);
```

this scale the big image but it doesn't fit the whole screen "img - bitmap is like an background image "

Someone can help me to understand the resize basics (I'm new so finding hard to understand resizing) to resize image to fit screen and resize any image to smaller one and place it in any location i like .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store your bitmap as a source for manipulation and display it using ImageView:

```
Bitmap realImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePathFromActivity.toString());

Bitmap newBitmap = scaleDown(realImage, MAX_IMAGE_SIZE, true);


imageView.setImageBitmap(newBitmap);


//scale down method
public static Bitmap scaleDown(Bitmap realImage, float maxImageSize,
        boolean filter) {
    float ratio = Math.min(
            (float) maxImageSize / realImage.getWidth(),
            (float) maxImageSize / realImage.getHeight());
    int width = Math.round((float) ratio * realImage.getWidth());
    int height = Math.round((float) ratio * realImage.getHeight());

    Bitmap newBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(realImage, width,
            height, filter);
    return newBitmap;
}
```

And set your ImageView's width and height to "`fill_parent`".

Comment: Thx for the help, but i got ForceQuit message since I'm trying to draw image in surface view where already i got few images