# Compress photo taken by android camera before upload to server

Tags: android, upload, compression

I am using this code to upload an image from the android camera to a server:

```
        miFoto = params[0];
        try { 
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            httpclient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.myserver.com/upload.php");
            File file = new File(miFoto);
            MultipartEntity mpEntity = new MultipartEntity();
            ContentBody foto = new FileBody(file, "image/jpeg");
            mpEntity.addPart("fotoUp", foto);
            httppost.setEntity(mpEntity);
            httpclient.execute(httppost);
            httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
```

The problem is that file size is too big. I have tried some ways to compress the image before upload it, but as I am a beginner in android, it is being impossible for me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you could resize the image to a lower resolution and rewrite the file, then upload it. The process of resizing can be seen here.

[How to resize image (Bitmap) to a given size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8471226/how-to-resize-image-bitmap-to-for-examle-800x480-in-code)