# Android uploading image AWS- resize

Tags: android, amazon-s3

I upload files to AWS S3 server wth that code:

```
private void beginUpload(String filePath) {
        if (filePath == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Could not find the filepath of the selected file",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
        File file = new File(filePath);
        TransferObserver observer = transferUtility.upload(AWSConfiguration.BUCKET_NAME, file.getName(),
                file);

    }
```

Before uploading I want to resize an image (not on my phone but only on server) to occupy less memory. How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming yout `file` is bitmap lets create `Bitmap` object like [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8710515/reading-an-image-file-into-bitmap-from-sdcard-why-am-i-getting-a-nullpointerexc) and then resize it like [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8471226/how-to-resize-image-bitmap-to-a-given-size). Create new file with resized bitmap like [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7769806/convert-bitmap-to-file), send it and remove file on the end.