# How to resize and align to center TextView to ImageView in relative layout - android sdk 10

Tags: android, imageview, android-relativelayout

I'm playing with Android `SDK 10` (I want to support devices from `sdk 10`)

I can't figure how to auto center the text in a `Imageview`.

The only way I can think of to center the text is to use padding, but I don't like it, it must be a better solution.

1. Resizing Image from asset is not working

   ```
   InputStream ims = context.getAssets().open("myimage.png");
   Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(ims, null);
   d.setBounds(0, 0, (int)(d.getIntrinsicWidth()*0.5),
   (int)(d.getIntrinsicHeight()*0.5));

   ScaleDrawable sd = new ScaleDrawable(d,0,px,py);
   ims.close();
   Image = new ImageView(context);
   Image.setImageDrawable(sd);
   Image.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
   layout.addView(Image);

   TextView t = new TextView(this.context);
   t.setText(r.toString());
   t.setTextSize(80);
   t.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
   layout.addView(t);
   ```

Is there  a way to add the text to image asset (`ImageView`) ?

Right now I added the `TextView` and `ImageView` in a `RelativeLayout`.

What is the best practice to create a group of asset image and text so that when I move the image the text is following (centered )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one worked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8471226/how-to-resize-image-bitmap-to-a-given-sizehttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/8471226/how-to-resize-image-bitmap-to-a-given-size

combined with the answer of @Dhananjay Sarsonia

Answer (score 1):

You can always add the CENTER_HORIZONTAL rule to the RelativeLayout, so all of its children remain centered horizontally.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. 
Keep Framelayout as the parent layout where you are adding the views.
Now use LayoutParams to set the ImageView's gravity, height and width.

```
  LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
  layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
  imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Now in the FrameLayout first add the Imageview and then the textview. Do not change anything for the textview.

```
 frameLayout.addView(imageView);
 frameLayout.addView(text);
```

Comment: it doesn't work, I will update the code with part of my class

Comment: Actually it is working, bu is not centered because of the first problem. The ScaleDrawable is not resizing the image. Do you have any ideea why ?

Comment: Instead of using the Scalable Drawable you can 
Add calculateInSampleSize() and decodeSampledBitmapFromResource() from [link](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)
Calculate the required Width and required Height image you want and
 pass those values to calculateInSampleSize().
Also set the Scaletype of the ImageView according to your needs

Comment: I will take a look and if is what I need I will pick this answer. Thank you