# How get resized bitmap in decodeResource

Tags: android, bitmap, drawable, bitmapfactory

I'm trying to decode a drawable resource into a bitmap like below.

```
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inScaled = true;
        int destinationDimension = 128;
        options.outHeight = destinationDimension;
        options.outWidth = destinationDimension;
        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), defaultImage, options);
        Log.d(TAG, "height = " + bmp.getHeight() + " width = " + bmp.getWidth());
```

But somehow the decoded bitmap is of dimesion 1344x1344.

```
    height = 1344 width = 1344
```

How can i get bitmap of dimension 128x128.

Answer (score 1):

`options.outHeight` is used as an output of `BitmapFactory.decodeResource`.

You can clearly identify them by `options.out<...>`. So after we decodeResource the Bitmap, the resulting height and width will be written into `options.outHeight` and `options.outWidth`

> So, can we resize bitmap in decodeResource?

Yes, and No.

We can resize by using `inSampleSize`. However, this will scale the bitmap for 2^n. Detail see here for calculation for inSampleSize: https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap

To scale bitmap to our destination width/height, use `Bitmap.createScaledBitmap`. See here: [How to resize image (Bitmap) to a given size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8471226/how-to-resize-image-bitmap-to-a-given-size).