# Resize image to fit screen size and resolution in Android

Tags: android, image, resolution, resize-image

I have an Android application to show images with `viewPager`. The images is in fixed size, so in some Android devices they appear with an empty border according to screen size and screen resolution.

Is there and way to resize the image to fit the screen?

It's not possible to put more than one image size in project, because I have more than 500 images.

Comment: have you tried `android:scaleType="..."` for your ImageView

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8268593/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try the different scaleTypes available. [The documentation can be found here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html)
and (which I prefer) [here is a very nice collection of examples](http://etcodehome.blogspot.de/2011/05/android-imageview-scaletype-samples.html) of what these scaleTypes look like.

If you just want your image to be stretched and do not care about losing the aspect ratio, you might want to go with `scaleType: fitXY`

Comment: This also work with me, but when I rotate the screen it became very bad and stretched