# ImageView and large GIF downsampling

Tags: android, android-imageview, gif, bitmapfactory

I'm displaying JPG/GIF/PNG in an `ImageView`. I've followed the following guidelines to scale large images appropriately, with the exception of using `BitmapFactory.decodeStream` (downloaded from a URL) instead of `BitmapFactory.decodeResource`:

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

This works great for JPG and PNG, but not at all for GIFs as the GIF does not display and I get the *Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture* message.

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: I guess there is something I'm missing: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3072

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After creating Bitmap, check its dimensions and downscale yourself using [Bitmap.createScaledBitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createScaledBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20boolean%29) if needed.

How to get maximal dimensions of texture is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7428996/hw-accelerated-activity-how-to-get-opengl-texture-size-limit).

Also watch for possible artifacts as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8420802/resize-image-from-file/13252754#13252754).

Comment: Does that apply to animated gifs?

Comment: BitmapFactory won't decode animated gifs, only 1st frame.